Serial client display no output but logic analyzer verifies output is sent
I'm using a serial/USB adapter (FTDI breakout) to talk to an old oscilloscope, and picocom as client  (invoked via picocom -b 9600 /dev/ttyUSB0 -f h). The scope requires hardware flow control, but its very finicky and I've had to short the RTS/CTS lines to even get it to boot. My issue is that even though everything appears to be wired correctly, and I'm using the correct baud and encoding (9600 8N1), I get no output from the serial client. What doubly interesting is that if I reverse RX/TX, I do get output, but it's gibberish. Just as a sanity check, I hooked up the breakout to a logic analyzer, and I can see ASCII output coming through at the baud rates and using the 8N1 configuration, but picocom still produces no output. I've tried a few other serial clients with no luck. Wondering what the issue could be.
For context, here's a diagram of how I've wired everything up:


"Wondering what the issue could be" - Your summation lacks any details, and is full of ambiguities. You have "short[ed] the RTS/CTS lines" (somewhere, somehow) yet still execute picocom with HW flow control?

I'm shorting the RTS/CTS lines on the DB9 connector, which is a common debug strategy for situations where hardware flow control is being flaky. Enabling hardware flow control for picocom makes no difference, tried it with each setting. I still get no output in the serial client.

If it's finicky, perhaps the voltage levels are too low. Look for -5V on an idle TX output pin, compared with common. Are you sure it is RS232 and not some other proprietary standard over DB9? Don't you need to send some chars to get it to reply?

Yep, I'm sure it's RS232. The logic analyzer is able to decode the signals, and I see plain ASCII text via the decoded signals. I tried sending a few characters to get it to reply, but still received no output. I've also tested this particular USB/serial adapter looped back to make sure it works, and it does.

I feel like I almost have too much information here. The core of this question is, if a serial device is sending data, and you can tell that the data is being sent correctly because you can see what's going with a logic analyzer, what would stop a serial terminal from outputting that data?

I worry that when you say you are using an "FTDI breakout" board, that it is working at TTL levels as many of them do. You would need a version that changes the 0V to 5V levels to -5V and +5V.

@meuh has a valid concern since RS-232 signals are not logic (e.g. TTL) signals, so how are you able capture such signals with a "logic analyzer"? BTW you overuse the word "output", e.g "picocom still produces no output" (meaning no display?) For a computer system, input and output are always relative to the CPU. If it's relative to something else, clearly state the perspective, like you did for "I get no output from the serial client".

"what would stop a serial terminal from outputting that data?" - By "outputting" you presumably mean display? The two most common reasons for no reception (especially since a loopback works) are: (1) miswiring; i.e. an output (source) is not connected to the input (sink or destination). (2) incompatible signals (not really sure if garbage would result). "if I reverse RX/TX, I do get output, but it's gibberish" - Almost sounds like it can be both #1 and #2. That's why I use a 'scope (and not a "logic analyzer") to check the serial signals.

Just to clarify, my breakout has a Max3232 onboard, but I can actually simplify this  a bit further. I started using the breakout to make it easier to probe what was going on, but my original test used a standard RS323/USB cable, of which I have a few, mostly the varieties with lights on the case to indicate which lines are active. I have a few DB9 gender changer adapters, and I opened one up and used it to do things like tie RTS to CTS, reverse RX/TX and split off lines through a level shifter to my logic analyzer. All of the behaviors were the same.
